# Utilising a queue in a python class - ''function' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, queue

I've forked a library for creating and rendering menu's on a 16x2 LVC/VFD and added some functionality for scrolling messages across the display. This works well but the issue I have is that if you try to display another message while this is happening the display will become corrupted. The best solution I can come up for this is utilising a queue, so each message function is queued behind the next. However I get issues with it being in a thread.

Here's the start of my working class:

```
class RpiLCDMenu(BaseMenu):
def __init__(self, pin_rs=26, pin_e=19, pins_db=[13, 6, 5, 21], GPIO=None, scrolling_menu=False):
    """
    Initialize menu
    """
    self.lcd_queue = queue.LifoQueue(maxsize=0)
    self.scrolling_menu = scrolling_menu

    self.pin_rs = pin_rs
    self.pin_e = pin_e
    self.pins_db = pins_db
    self.GPIO = GPIO

    self.lcd = RpiLCDHwd(self.pin_rs, self.pin_e, self.pins_db, self.GPIO)
    self.lcd.initDisplay()
    # clear it once in case of corruption
    self.clearDisplay()
    self.message("Hello")


    super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
```

However if I use a queue instead and try to utilise it, the lcd still gets initialsed but the message fails with:

'function' object is not subscriptable

Not working:

```
class RpiLCDMenu(BaseMenu):
def __init__(self, pin_rs=26, pin_e=19, pins_db=[13, 6, 5, 21], GPIO=None, scrolling_menu=False):
    """
    Initialize menu
    """
    self.lcd_queue = queue.LifoQueue(maxsize=0)
    self.scrolling_menu = scrolling_menu

    self.pin_rs = pin_rs
    self.pin_e = pin_e
    self.pins_db = pins_db
    self.GPIO = GPIO


    # todo implement message queue to avoid corruption
    self.lcd_queue_processor()

    super(self.__class__, self).__init__()

def lcd_queue_processor(self):
    print("queue started")
    self.lcd = RpiLCDHwd(self.pin_rs, self.pin_e, self.pins_db, self.GPIO)
    self.lcd.initDisplay()
    # clear it once in case of corruption
    self.clearDisplay()
    self.message("Hello")

    while True:
        print("running")
        items = self.lcd_queue.get()
        func = items[0]
        args = items[1:]
        func(*args)
```

I'm unsure why the message function stops working in this instance.

I am by no means a developer, so any help appreciated! Full library...

https://github.com/domb84/rpi-lcd-menu

Comment: Oddly I've found if I change the double quotes to single quotes it seems ok - it's actually the code before the queue that was an issue. However, the queue isn't processing. It just sits there. But thats a different issue...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're pushing a function into the queue.
The issue is at

```
items = self.lcd_queue.get()
func = items[0]
args = items[1:]
```

`get()` only returns a single item (in your case a function) which you can't index on.

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get)

Comment: it can be indexed, if the function and args are pushed as a tuple/list in the queue. So, when the `get` method is used, it returns a single item which would be a tuple/list.

Comment: I pass the following into the queue which seem to get processed now I've changed "hello" to 'hello'. Not sure why double quotes works out of the queue but not within it though.

self.lcd_queue.put(lcd_render, fixed_text)

Comment: @domb84 , the error is here `self.lcd_queue.put(lcd_render, fixed_text) ` . Queue `put` method accepts one item. So, make the args as a tuple and put it in the queue.
Like: `self.lcd_queue.put((lcd_render, fixed_text))`